# Fields in Windows Chrome differ in height from all other browsers, despite no height setting

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome

Apologies for the live link but I am unable to replicate this in JSFiddle or others.

I am having an issue with the height of input fields in Windows Chrome only.

Currently my inputs are outputting at 56px high.

However, the font size is `16px`, the padding is `8px` all round and the bottom border is `3px` therefore the input, including border, should only be `35px` Yet it is outputting `20px` taller.

This is how the look on Windows Chrome:

[image]

And here is the live link, you will find the form at the bottom of the page if you click 'contact us'

### [therightethos.francesca-designed.me](http://therightethos.francesca-designed.me)

Comment: A font size of 16px can still be put in a line height that is greater (or even smaller) than that. So you need line height, padding, border, margin, and then still, maybe, an input behaves differently.

Comment: @GolezTrol even providing a line-height of 16px does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It has a height of 37px, which is set by the browser itself and is never overruled in your CSS. To the height, the padding and border are added (2x8 + 3), bringing the total to 56px.